# Diy plant saucers

Tags: planting

I was checking amazon and home depot, and 12” sturdy plastic saucers start at $3.50 each. I find them expensive.

Is there any way to build these saucers for cheaper? I searched Pinterest and there aren’t many diy for saucers.